# Searching for an efficient algorithm for: When was the chatroom empty?

Tags: algorithm

A protocol (in form of a tableview) is keeping track on the activity of all its users (wlog: there are n users), when they entered and when they left the chat room.

The table view consists of the three columns, user, time user logged in, time user logged out.

I am now tasked to find an algorithm, which finds out, when the chat room is empty.

A fast and easy way seems to me to first define:

An empty chatroom has the value: 0

If a person enters the chatroom, the value of the chatroom increases by 1

If a person leaves the chatroom, the value of the chatroom decreases by 1

Now I sort all times, 2*n, in a list and simply check for every time the current value of the room and check everytime, if the current value is 0, in which cases I win, jobs done.

Overall the algorithm may take me O(n* log(n)) time, however I wonder, if there is a faster/better way doing this. I appreciate any constructive comment or answer.

As always thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't the log already sorted?  Then its just an O(n) scan.

Comment: That's pretty much the best you can do (sort the time events) and look find time range where the user logged in is 0. If you are able to change how the software keeps track of the events, get it to log the events in order, which then will make any processing of it O(n).